# How can you replace a value via a LEFT JOIN in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table which contains a set of translations and I want to query the original table with the translations inserted (if a translation exists). For example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id TEXT,
  key TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE translations (
  key TEXT,
  value TEXT  
);

INSERT INTO foo(id, key) VALUES('1', '1');
INSERT INTO foo(id, key) VALUES('2', '2');
INSERT INTO foo(id, key) VALUES('3', '5');
INSERT INTO foo(id, key) VALUES('4', '6');

INSERT INTO translations(key, value) VALUES('5', '7');
INSERT INTO translations(key, value) VALUES('6', '8');
```

I want a query to return the table:

```
1 1
2 2
3 7
4 8
```

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ee8cc

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```
SELECT f.id, f.key, COALESCE(t.value, f.key) AS TranslatedKey
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN translations t
ON f.key = t.key
```

with a left join the values from `t` will be null if no match is found.  `COALESCE` returns the first non-null value from the list of inputs.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA you must have missed my edit.  That's been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using case:

```
SELECT f.id,
CASE WHEN t.key IS NULL THEN f.key ELSE t.value END AS Column2
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN translations t ON f.key=t.key
```

The coalesce way is neater in my opinion though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,b.value  from foo a left join translations b on a.key = b.key
```

hope it helps..

Comment: you didnt actually replace the value, only added another column